# Retrieve a package with commas inside - sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I need to retrieve a package with a comma inside by command -> `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -p "package, name"`.

I understand `-p` accepts multiple packages in one go with comma as a separator. This makes me no idea how to pass in a package name with comma inside.

**Already tested these scenarios below, they do not work:**

- double-quoted package name,
- double-quoted package name with Back-slashed comma,
- double-quoted package name with double back-slashed comma

Comment: Looks like this bug is still in sfdx after all these years and I found your post when googling for what else I could try. Did you ever find a way around this?  I have also tried in ant by escaping as html and xml versions of a comma with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping the comma would have been my first approach - however if you execute the `sfdx` command in a shell, then the shell will also interpret characters in arguments.
You could try to "double-escape", e.g. write `... "package\\, name"`. The shell would interpret `\\` as an escaped backslash sign and pass one backslash sign towards the sfdx command.

Comment: good point,  I did just give it a try, the command still doesn't accept -> `ERROR running force:mdapi:retrieve:  The metadata retrieve operation failed: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: No package named 'package\' found`

Comment: This looks like the `sfdx` command sees the backslash character in its argument but doesn't interpret it as an escape character.
I've tried URL encoding the comma and space in the package name, thinking that `sfdx` being a node.js tool this could lead somewhere - but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

As [source:retrieve](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_retrieve) is available now, it is better to use this latest retrieve method (mdapi had some bugs)

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -n "Package1, PackageName With Spaces, Package3"
```

Comment: Good to know. However, trying this command results in the same error that a package with a comma in its name can not be retrieved.

Comment: Could you point out what bugs mdapi could have? Just out of curiosity.