# Salesforce CLI Creating a Record With Quotes In String

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

We are running into an issue with the CLI where we can't seem to create a record where one of its fields needs to have quotes in it. For example **sfdx force:data:record:create -s SomeObject -v 'SomeField=["SomeId"]'** simply looks like this once inserted **SomeField => [SomeId]**. What is stranger is that if we do **'SomeField=[""""SomeId""""]'** it will also insert as **SomeField => [SomeId]**. It is almost like the cli is replacing the quotes. How do we get the cli to keep the quotes in the string when creating a record?

Comment: Interesting. Probably a command line feature, at least in windows. See the section `Last example explained` here http://www.windowsinspired.com/understanding-the-command-line-string-and-arguments-received-by-a-windows-program/ . I try using a ^ to escape quotes

Comment: Yeah Im in powershell and for instance if you write-host 'SomeField=["SomeId"]' It will look fine. That was my inital though that it was just a command line problem, but Ive tried all escapes which for powershell is backtick, tried backslash, tried the carot for shoots and giggles. Im convinced its not a command line feature

Comment: I should say the article you mentioned does outline an issue that could be the issue but doesn't exactly apply because I am using single quotes to create the string that is an issue when using double quotes inside a double quoted string

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_data.htm) mentions needing double quotes to enclose field-value pairs and, in my quick testing, found the same issues you did with trying to escape double quotes to include as a value. Interestingly, I found another question with frustrations with escaping [commas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/279031/retrieve-a-package-with-commas-inside-sfdx-forcemdapiretrieve)

Comment: So I figured it out though i need to work out why so ill hold off on answering my own question "FieldA=SomeValue FieldB='[\\`"SomeValue\\`"]'". I encased it in single quotes, though there is no space like the documentation says when to use it it needed it. The backtick is for powershell escape the backslash is for JSON escape. Again still working on the details but someway somehow this solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from some investigation I have solved it, Salesforce documentation fails to mention this and it seems to only apply to double quotes but when using them to transmit data in there format *(i.e sfdx force:data:record:create)* you need to surround the value in single quotes. This is a missing detail to there documentation that says you only need them if spaces are in the value. Furthermore you need to add a JSON escape backslash. This only applies to double quotes from what I found other special JSON characters don't need to be escaped. For example \n will just put in a \n into the string you are trying to set. 
Example ..

---

`sfdx force:data:record:create -s SomeObject -v "SomeField=["SomeId"]"` will result in SomeField being *[SomeId]*

`sfdx force:data:record:create -s SomeObject -v "SomeField=[\"SomeId\"]"` will also result in SomeField being *[SomeId]*

`sfdx force:data:record:create -s SomeObject -v "SomeField='[\"SomeId\"]'"` will also give the desired result of SomeField being *["SomeId"]*

`sfdx force:data:record:create -s SomeObject -v "SomeField='[\"Some\Id\"]'"` will result in SomeField being *["Some\Id"]*

---

P.S Whatever command line you are in don't forget your escape characters those will also be necessary.